# django uwsgi no module named site

Tags: python, django, pip, uwsgi, wsgi

First of all, I'm aware of many related questions exist but none of them solved my problem.
I installed uwsgi using `sudo pip3 install uwsgi` on centOs 7 when my virtualenv is activated. I try to run it with command

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --module ashpazi.wsgi --ini ../ini_files/ashpazi.ini
```

I get this error

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

This is my `ashpazi.ini` file

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /root/projects/ashpazi
home  = /root/projects/venv
module = ashpazi.wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

uid = root
gid = nginx
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=ashpazi.settings
plugin = python3.6
socket = /root/projects/sockets/ashapazi.sock
chmod-socket = 777
vacuum = true
```

Running `which uwsgi` returns `/usr/bin/uwsgi` which is not in virtualenv directory.

And running `sudo pip3 show uwsgi` returns this:

```
Name: uWSGI
Version: 2.0.15
Summary: The uWSGI server
Home-page: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
Author: Unbit
Author-email: info@unbit.it
License: GPL2
Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

which states that uwsgi is in `python2.7` folder and not `python3.6` I'm using in my django project. 
How can I solve this problem?

**Edit:**

I'm using `sudo pip3 install uwsgi` because using it without sudo will result in this error

```
*** uWSGI compiling embedded plugins ***
[gcc -pthread] plugins/python/python_plugin.o
In file included from plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1:0:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file 

or directory
 #include <Python.h>
                ^
    compilation terminated.

----------------------------------------
Command "/root/projects/venv/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-
yz2o1zz3/uwsgi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', 
'\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record 
/tmp/pip-o6hcf_v3-record/install-record.txt --single-version-
externally-managed --compile --install-headers 
/root/projects/venv/include/site/python3.6/uwsgi" failed with error 
code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-yz2o1zz3/uwsgi/
```

Comment: can you share the traceback of the error message

Comment: You should not be using ``sudo pip3 install uwsgi`` when installing into a virtualenv. Use just ``pip install uwsgi`` after activating virtualenv. By doing what you did you installed it into system Python.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton can you please let us know why pip3 installs it to the system, while pip installs in in the venv

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton when i don't use sudo i get an error, I updated the question and included the error.

Comment: Depending on how sudo is configured, it may not inherit your environment variables from your user account and so will not find correct ``pip3``. Try running ``sudo which pip3`` and see what you get.

Comment: At this point any problems are possibly because you are doing stuff in ``/root``. This directory may only be accessible to ``root``. Better to put your stuff elsewhere if you want to do this as a non root user. Also uninstall ``uwsgi`` from system Python to make sure doesn't conflict in any way.

Comment: That error also doesn't include the earlier bit which tells you what the actual cause of the problem was.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton you were right, I included the actual error as well.

Comment: That means you do not have the ``-devel`` variant of the Python package installed. You will not be able to install Python packages with C extensions if you do not install it.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton i installed python34-devel (tried python36-devel but doesn't exists) now when i create virtual env with `python3 -m venv /path/to/venv` it uses python34. uwsgi will get installed but my django project won't run any more!

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same problem, solution im my case was to install python-devel with python version. Example python36u you must  install python36u-devel and then install "pip3.6 install uwsgi".

Answer (score 0):

Finally i figured it out. In order to use uwsgi in pip3 i had to first install python36u-devel. Now uwsgi is installed in venv directory.

```
removing all existing uwsgi packages installed from pip or system package manager
sudo yum install python36u-devel
. venv/bin/activate (using virtual envirement to avoid installing it globally)
pip3 install uwsgi
```